# Django REST Framework Serialize Multiple Models into one "Timeline"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, polymorphism

I have an abstract base "Post" model with multiple child models that have their own required fields.

I have serialized these different post types into something that looks like this

```
"timeline": {
    "text": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "heading": "Yea",
            "text": "hello world",
            "render": "<p>\n  Yea\n</p>\n<p>\n  hello world\n</p>\n",
            "created_on": "2018-08-18T16:05:45.910124Z"
        }
    ],
    "video": [],
    "image": []
}
```

What I'm trying to do is be able to display them chronologically on the front end.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: can you post your models both Post and derived child models? What field do you want to use for ordering?

Comment: Given that your base model has a datefield can't you just use the built in `.order_by('fieldname')` when fetching your data?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you could just sort the whole thing before sending it to the frontend. I assume you have a `list of dict` like above with

```
posts = [{'timeline: { ... }}, {'timeline: { ... }}, ...]
```

like in your example, so [to sort it in-place](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort), it would be

```
posts.sort(key=lambda t: t['timeline']['text'][0]['created_on'])
```

That would put all the objects in chronological order.

Comment: Maybe worth noting; should probably do it via SQL if possible since this can create unwanted behaviour if using pagination when fetching all posts. And thus only sorting a part of all the posts